# Error Number: 1064 Ошибка синтаксиса

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

Доброго дня!

Работаю с CI. Выполняю запрос:

```
function edit_template($data = array())
{
    if ($data)
    {
        $sql = "
            UPDATE {$this->_db}
            SET
                title = " . $this->db->escape($data['title']) . ",
                                    check = " . $this->db->escape($data['check']) . ",
                message = " . $this->db->escape($data['message']) . "
            WHERE id = " . $this->db->escape($data['id']) . "
        ";

        $this->db->query($sql);

        if ($this->db->affected_rows())
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

> **Error Number: 1064**
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'check = '1', message = '23', WHERE id = '1'' at line 4
>
> UPDATE sms_template SET title = 'Пополнение счета', check = '1',
>   message = '23', WHERE id = '1'

Что я делаю не так?
Без строки `check = " . $this->db->escape($data['check']) . ",` все работает без ошибок.

Благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: `check` какой тип в таблице имеет и в вашем php?

Comment: Тип - INT. Длинна 11

Comment: А положить пытаетесь строку?

Comment: я пробовал менять тип на varchar или text - результат остается таким же.

Comment: Это сработало! Спасибо

Comment: Перенес код в ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Оберните все названия таблиц и полей в спец-кавычки
2) Манипулируйте данными, приводя их к правильному типу. Не следует заворачивать в кавычки  целочисленные переменные.

```
$sql = "
       UPDATE `{$this->_db}`
       SET
           `title` = " . $this->db->escape($data['title']) . ",
           `check` = " . intval($data['check']) . ",
           `message` = " . $this->db->escape($data['message']) . "
       WHERE `id` = " . intval($data['id']) . "
   ";
```

Comment: Почему ты не сказал, что нужно использовать PDO?